# Hard coded in java script, Some suggestions to decrease this code is appreciated

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried using js createElement, setAttribute,appendChild for achieving things.

**original div**

```
<div class = "form-row" id="components">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
        <label for="component">Component</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="component" placeholder ="component" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
        <label for="component">Each price</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" min=0 placeholder = "Each Price" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

**function to append elements to parent div**

```
function components(){
    var x = document.getElementById("components");

    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.setAttribute("class","form-group col-md-3 mb-0")


    var item = document.createElement("Input");
    item.setAttribute("type","text");
    item.setAttribute("id","item");
    item.setAttribute("value","");
    item.setAttribute("class","form-control");
    item.setAttribute("placeholder","item");

    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.setAttribute("class","form-group col-md-3 mb-0")

    var price = document.createElement("Input");
    price.setAttribute("type","number");
    price.setAttribute("id","price");
    price.setAttribute("min",0);
    price.setAttribute("value","");
    price.setAttribute("class","form-control");
    price.setAttribute("placeholder","price");

    div1.appendChild(item);
    div2.appendChild(price);

    x.appendChild(div1);
    x.appendChild(div2);
}
```

The above function works with onclick event and creates child divs.

Comment: Do you consider on using something like jQuery, or do you prefer just plain Javascript?

Comment: i don't have much idea of jQuery , so i have tried in JS. But there is no preference of javascript, i will check with jQuey too.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You have no description of what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: You may want to look into javascript minifiers/uglifiers, I use ether webpack or if I need fast access minifier I use https://uglifyjs.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just set the `innerHTML` of the container?

```
function components(){
    var x = document.getElementById("components");
    x.innerHTML += `
<div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
  <label for="component">Component</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="component" placeholder ="component" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
  <label for="component">Each price</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" min=0 placeholder = "Each Price" value="">
</div>
    `;
}
```

It's not entirely clear, but if you're intending on calling `components` multiple times, use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead, to avoid corrupting the existing elements in the container (so that inputs with values don't get reset, and so that event listeners attached to children (if any) don't get lost):

```
function components(){
    var x = document.getElementById("components");
    x.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
<div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
  <label for="component">Component</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="component" placeholder ="component" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
  <label for="component">Each price</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" min=0 placeholder = "Each Price" value="">
</div>
    `);
}
```

Comment: i call the function multiple times, then inner html is being duplicated , for 1st time it creating one another row on 2nd call it creating 2 other rows, as duplication of inner html is happening(on second call total 4 rows is being created).